# Android, create differents kind of jsonObject

Tags: android, json

I would like to create a generic class which create my jsonObject.
Is it possible to create a class which can create differents kind of objects like

```
{"chunkSize":10,"filters"
[{"field":"segmentOwners.id","operator":"EQUAL","value":"11578","valueType":"java.lang.Integer"},
{"field":"language","operator":"EQUAL","value":"FR","valueType":"java.lang.String"},
{"field":"customerId","operator":"EQUAL","value":"77","valueType":"java.lang.Integer"}]
,"orderBy":[{"field":"creationTime","order":"DESC"}],"page":0}
```

OR just a simple request:

```
{login:"mylogin",pwd:"mypwd"}
```

I tried something like:

```
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
        byte[] result = null;
        Iterator iter = mData.entrySet().iterator();

       JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        Iterator it = mData.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            try {
                jsonObj.put((String) pairs.getKey(), (String) pairs.getValue());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
        }
```

But i'm not sure that is the same kind of hashmap (string, jsonObjet...?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create instances of `JSONObject` from JSON strings, just do the following:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject("<your json string>");
```

Comment: +1.  `JSONObject` doesn't care about the contents of the string, so long as they are valid JSON.  The resultant `JSONObject` will respond to `getInt("chunkSize")` or `getString("login")` or `getJSONArray("filters")`; or, if the object does not have that key, it will throw a `JSONException`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create generic container class (i.e. `DataContainer`) which would expose unified API no matter of what data it holds (i.e. `setFromJson()`, `getData()`). Then create separate object for each data structure (i.e. `DataLogin`, `DataSomething`). Then when you fetch your json data from remote source, you could i.e. create `DataLogin` object and hand it to your `DataContainer` (or pass json to DataContainer so it could detect `DataLogin` should be used and create it itself, but that require some logic which may not be best approach). Then all methods that are expected to work on your json data can be handed DataContainer object and method could do `getType()` on it (you need to set type yourself of course), which would return what data is stored and then `getData()` to get the data iself to work on.